# :root imported CSS not working in safari and IE 11

Tags: html, css, safari, internet-explorer-11, css-variables

`:root` Selector is not working in some of the browsers.

**Code:**

```css
:root {
    --blue: #4d6fd3;
    --yellow: #d8c812;
}
h1{
    color: var(--blue);
}
h2{
    color: var(--yellow);
}
```

```html
<h1>This is a heading with blue color</h1>
<h2>This is a heading with yellow color</h2>
```

These imported CSS are not applied in **Safari 5.1.7** and **IE11**.

Comment: CSS variables are [not supported](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-variables) in IE11.

Comment: What version of Safari? As stated, IE11 doesn't support the feature at all.

Comment: **Safari 5.1.7**

Comment: This browser is 5 years old and has not received any update (not even security ones) since then... Stop using it right now, for your computer's safety. Use a virtual machine to test the current version (10.1.2) directly on osX

Comment: And if you wonder, it does work on up to date safari.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This css3 selector works fine in all edge browser, so have a little issues, please see my image, and I hope that help you.

[image]